# Cannot understand why the html tag does not have both head and body as child nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having a problem traversing the DOM tree. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <script src="main.js"></script>
   <title>DOM Traversing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href="">One</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
    </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var rootNodeChildren = document.childNodes;
var rootNodeChild;

for (var i = 0; i < rootNodeChildren.length; ++i) {
    rootNodeChild = rootNodeChildren[i];
    console.log(rootNodeChild);
    console.log(rootNodeChild.childNodes.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < rootNodeChild.childNodes.length; ++j) {
        console.log(rootNodeChild.childNodes[j]);
    }
}
```

This this the result of the following code:

[image]

The document object has 2 children

1. DOCTYPE html
2. html tag

The html tag should have 2 children as well.

1. head tag
2. body tag

But the output shows that html tag has only one child i.e. head tag

Can someone please explain why that is?

In the example, the HTML is not relevant but I intend to write a recursive function to traverse all elements of DOM tree.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Try logging `rootNodeChild.childNodes[i].tagName` rather than the object. Also, use `children` instead of `childNodes`, so you skip the text nodes.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to script execution time.

The script runs before the body element is present on the DOM: therefore it correctly tells you that the head element is the only child...at the time.

Move your script towards the bottom and it'll include the body element in your count.

Comment: …or execute the function onload.